# Very basic question about limits

Tags: limits, functions

I have a very basic question about limits that confuses me usually when simplifying expressions.

Suppose we have a continuous function $f(x)$ where $x \in \mathbb R$, And we have also $f(r) = 0$.
Let's consider another function $$g(x)= {f(x)\cdot x^2\over f(x)}$$

**My questions are**:

- Can we write $g(x) = x^2$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ ?
- Do we need to know the limits of $f(x)$ at $r^+$ and $r^-$?
  I think another form of this question is if:
  $$\ell = \lim_{x\to r}{f(x) \over f(x)}$$
  Does $\ell$ evaluates always to 1?

Comment: If $f(r)=0$, then $g$ isn't even defined at $r$.

Comment: @JackM Can you explain why?

Comment: Because $g(r)$ would be $0/0$, and when you go look up $0/0$ in the division table in the Big Cosmic Book Of Answers To All Arithmetical Questions, it isn't listed. It's undefined.

Comment: $\frac x x$ is equal to $1$ for all $x$ other than $0$, but it's still undefined at $0$.

Comment: It evaluates it to $1$ at every $x\ne 0$, and that implies that the limit as $x\to 0$ is indeed $1$. But that still tells you nothing about the value of the function at zero (which is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

Continuity of $f$ isn't required, only existence of the limit of $g$. The limits of $f$ to $r^{\pm}$ or to $r$ are irrelevant.

If the function is zero in a neighborhood of $r$, then the ratio cannot be evaluated and the limit of $g$ to $r$ is undefined.

Otherwise you can indeed indeed simplify and write

$$\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)h(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to r}h(x)=h(r)$$ (where $h(x)$ can be $1$ or $x^2$ or any continuous function).
But this doesn't allow you to write

$$g(x):=\frac{f(x)h(x)}{f(x)}=h(x)$$ for all $x$ because $g(r)$ is still undefined. You can fix that by adding

$$g(r):=h(r).$$

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Freshman42: of what ???

Answer (score 0):

1) No, because there is some real $r$ such that $f(r) = 0$.

2) Given that question, you don't have to. Note that if there is exactly one $r$ such that $f(r) = 0$, then
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x)x^{2}}{f(x)} = x^{2}
$$
for all $x \neq r$
(Considering only the case of exactly one $r$ is just for illustration convenience; you can try to generalize it.).
Recall that the concept of limit is about the behavior of a given function **near** a point without the function necessarily being defined at the point.
So $g(x) \to r^{2}$ as $x \to r$ by the fact that the function $x \mapsto x^{2}$ is continuous.

Comment: What about $f(x):=x\sqrt{\sin\frac1x}$ at $x=0$ ?

Comment: for all $x \neq r$ in the domain. @YvesDaoust

Comment: for all $x\ne r$, what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I was responding to your question

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, here we have got a random downvoting sh*t :D

Comment: Your sentence is unfinished.

Comment: Maybe I got your question wrong. So why did you post that question here??

Comment: Because "you can easily generalize it" left me unsatisfied, so I suggested a more nasty case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, it makes sense. Your unsatisfication makes my answer better. Thank you.